# Can't order TreeView in vertical order

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have an ASP.NET-page with two treeviews - each with two columns - in vertical order.
As long as the first treeview has an equal count of nodes, the treeviews are displayed in exact vertical order.
But when the first treeview has an unequal count of nodes, the first node of the second treeview is displayed to the right of the last node of the first treeview.
How can i prevent this?
I tried the tags ,

and .

Thanks in advance!

And here is a part from the Markup of my page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" runat="server" ID="updSearchFilter">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="PnlSearchFilter" runat="server" style="height:100%;">
            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="generic-button" runat="server" ID="btnFilter" OnClick="btnFilter_Click">
                <span id="s1" runat="server"><span id="s2" runat="server"><asp:Literal ID="l1" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources: Search, filter %>" /></span></span>
            </asp:LinkButton>
            <div style="width:100%;">
                <asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="tvBuFilter" ShowCheckBoxes="All" ExpandDepth="1" CssClass="treeView" NodeIndent="10" >
                    <NodeStyle CssClass="treeNode" />
                    <Nodes/>
                </asp:TreeView>
            </div>
            <div style="width:100%;">
                <asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="tvFeFilter" ShowCheckBoxes="All" ExpandDepth="1" CssClass="treeView" NodeIndent="10" >
                    <NodeStyle CssClass="treeNode" />
                    <Nodes/>
                </asp:TreeView>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
It works with `<div style="width:100%; clear: both;">`